# Clojure template engine to generate Java source

Tags: clojure, code-generation, template-engine

I am writing a Clojure program which need to generate a Java source. Is there a good idiomatic way/template engine for that.

In Java world I would probably use Velocity or Freemarker. I know I can still use them from Clojure, but wondering if there is better way.

Comment: To what end? Both compile to bytecode. How would introducing a Java representation benefit you?

Comment: I think my question was confusing, I have edited it. I did not mean "generate Java version of Clojure code", I meant if I need to generate Java source file in Clojure, what is the best way to go about it

Comment: Well, let me answer it then. I am using Clojure to implement an application which generates a Java application. Kind of jump start your Java development. So by definition I need to generate Java sources (along with other artifacts XML, html, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can take a look at [Rythm template engine](http://rythmengine.com/), which is much faster than Freemarker and Velocity, also much easier to use.

Document could be found at http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm-1.0.0-20121210/home

Note although the document is for play-rythm module, the most part of it also apply to pure rythm environment

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Clojure with [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) for the purpose you describe for quite some time now with good results. I 've also defined a helpful set of macros that make the invocation of the StringTemplate renderers from Clojure a breeze. **StringTemplate** is established, solid and used for heavy-weight compilers so it can't fail you. On simplicity / speed or other trade-offs I cannot comment.